# How to include config files in a boxfuse image (golang app)?

Tags: go, cloudcaptain

I am working on a golang server and i want to include some config files in the fused image. However, i am unable to find any documentation that can point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to package more than just the x64 binary, you can use Boxfuse's support for generic Linux x64 apps instead, where you can supply a tar.tg file: https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/linux-x64